# Regex capture data between String and \n character in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am learning python, I wanted to capture the data between 'NUMBER:' and \n

NUMBER: 3741733552\n556644

the number after the new line character in variable, hence cannot count on it to capture.

```
    re.search(r'NUMBER:(.*?)[\n]', string_data).group(1)
```

I tried above code(which is wrong) in vain, please help in capturing that number. Thank you.

Edit:

I have a String "NAME: KHAN NASEEM\n\n22972 LAHSER RD\n\n..." to which I used like the code

```
    name = re.search(r'NAME:\s*(.+)', string_data)
```

but the output I got is "KHAN NASEEM\n\n22972 LAHSER RD\n\n...", But I want only KHAN NASEEM only.

\n = string literal, not actual new line

Comment: Use `r'NUMBER:\s*(\d+)` or `r'NUMBER:\s*(.+)`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew The above solution worked \d is for digits and .+ is for chars if I encounter similar kind of a problem right?

Comment: `.` matches any char but a line break char. `\d` matches digits, but mind that in Python 3, it will match any Unicode digits. If you only need to mstch ASCII digits you will have to use `re.A` flag or just use `[0-9]`.

Comment: Use `NAME:\s*(.+)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew In NAME: KHAN NASEEM\n\n, I used  r'NAME:\s*(\w+) 'I am getting KHAN as output, what should I do to get NASEEM also, can you help me?

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew I Tried that NAME:\s*(.+) - but It is capturing whole chunk of data which is after NAME:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156583/discussion-between-srini-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: See https://ideone.com/wBuimo

Comment: Please Check This https://regex101.com/r/zY9xA3/30

Comment: What are you doing? Your regex fiddle is wrong, [this is the correct one](https://regex101.com/r/zY9xA3/31). You are not writing Python code, but playing around with regex101.com without understanding the relations between what you do at the online regex tester and how to use it later in the code. Please explain what your **real life** requirements are.

Comment: Sure, I have a String "NAME: KHAN NASEEM\n\n22972 LAHSER RD\n\n..." to which I used like the code you sent me through ideone `name = re.search(r'NAME:\s*(.+)', string_data)` but the output I got is "KHAN NASEEM\n\n22972 LAHSER RD\n\n...", I am using Python 3.6, But I want only KHAN NASEEM

Comment: Let's talk Python. You have a string literal `"NAME: KHAN NASEEM\n\n22972 LAHSER RD\n\n..."`. That means you have newlines in the *literal* string where you have `\n` in the *string literal*. So, your code must [look like this](https://ideone.com/j3bD2P). Please study Python string literals.

Comment: Sure, Thank you for your help and support, I will study what you have suggested

Comment: So, do you really have newlines or `r'\n'` = `"\\n"` in the string (a ``\`` followed with an `n` letter)?

Comment: I have \n (a \ followed with an n letter). Not actual new line

Comment: Where? In the code? In the console? In a file? Please share the image via imgur. The image proving you have just that text.

Comment: PAYEE NAME: KHAN NASEEM\n\n22972 LAHSER RD\n\nCHECK NUMBER: 150823520\n\nCHECK AMOUNT: $65.17\nWESTFIELD Ml 480334408 GRPID: MIF\xe2\x80\x99H\n\nRA REFERENCE ID: 2017080915600449\n\n \n\n \n\n20-89090\xe2\x80\x98 \xc2\xa300700 LHddOdSOG LZ\n\n'ATIENT: HUSIY M JIGNI 'V\n\nJBSCRIBER ID: 103517525 SUBSCRIBER NAME: NAHIDA Y DAKHO - This is the contents of the file

Comment: Please share the screenshot showing where this data is.

Comment: The data is in the database(mongo db), i store the data to a string, which looks like the above mentioned when i do `print(string_data)` and later I want to extract name from the string

Comment: Come on, these details must have been provided at the very beginning. Try to tag the question accordingly (add `mongodb` or `pymongo`) and maybe other experts will help you better. I think you have an issue with how data is transfered from the DB to Python.

Comment: `if 'NAME:' in string_data:`
        `payee_name = re.search(r' NAME:\s*(.+)', string_data)`
        `if payee_name:`
            `print("Payee Name: " + payee_name.group(1))`
    `return string_data` - out putlooks like this Payee Name: KHAN NASEEM\n\n22972 LAHSER RD\n\nCHECK NUMBER: 150823520\n\nCHECK AMOUNT: $65.17\nWESTFIELD Ml 480334408 GRPID: MIF\xe2\x80\x99H\n\nRA REFERENCE ID: 2017080915600449\n\n \n\n \n\n20-89090\xe2\x80\x98 \xc2\xa300700 LHddOdSOG LZ\n\n'ATIENT: HUSIY M JIGNI 'V\n\nJBSCRIBER ID: 103517525 SUBSCRIBER NAME: NAHIDA Y DAKHO

Comment: Yes, I understand, but a regex like `r'\bNAME:\s*(.+?)(?:\\n|$)'` is not a good solution because your string is "escaped". Your main problem is the escaped string.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, about the transfer. I will take a look at that part

Comment: Perfect, It worked fine, Thank you for baring my mistakes and helping me.

Comment: I posted with explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get all chars from `NAME:` up to the backslash followed with `n` letter, use

```
\bNAME:\s*(.+?)(?:\\n|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jEASp3/2).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `NAME:` - a `NAME:` substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.+?)` -  Group 1: one or more chars other than line breal chars, as few as possible
- `(?:\\n|$)` - either the end of string or a backslash followed with `n`

Below is the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ksFN73):

```
import re
s = r'NAME: KHAN NASEEM\n\n22972 LAHSER RD\n\n...' # Note r'' prefix: all \ are literal backslashes here!
m = re.search(r'\bNAME:\s*(.+?)(?:\\n|$)', s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1)) # => KHAN NASEEM
```

**NOTE**: You should check how text is fetched from the DB to Python. The `\n` should actually be newlines. Once fixed, you will just have to use

```
r'\bNAME:\s*(.+)'
```

A whole word `NAME:`, 0+ whitespaces, and Group 1 will capture one or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible (i.e. the rest of the line).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
s = "NUMBER: 3741733552\n556644"
final_data = re.findall('NUMBER:\s*(.*?)\n', s)
```

Output:

```
['3741733552']
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is my solution to your question. It is short and simple, also easy to read. You could get more complex with it, but I like to keep things easy :-). I hope this helps you!

```
>>> import re
>>> num = 'NUMBER: 3741733552\n556644'
>>> search = re.search(r'([0-9].*)', num).group(0)
>>> print(search)
3741733552
```